# Using s3 as a database rather than dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I have a whatsapp chatbot project in AWS.  I'm using DynamoDB as the database for the system.  I'm looking to port my data over to S3 thinking it'd be more affordable to store data in S3 rather than DynamoDB.  But I'm not sure it'd be a good fit as I'd lose key constraints and other functionality of a DB.

I'm not even sure if it is a good idea as I'm thinking of scenarios where I'd have to read, update and delete rows.  The idea of moving over to S3 was brought forward due to cost concerns.

Please tell me if moving over data of a project to S3 is a good idea.  If so, what steps would be changed?

Thank you.

Edit:
I'm thinking of writing the data from DynamoDB as json file in S3 rather than csv.  I think I have to go through many steps to do a simple update in case of csv.

2nd edit:
The idea turned out to be not the best way to go with.  I have no querying capabilities, no way to update the file (have to re-write the whole file with all the data) and data retrieval latency.  I'm sticking with dynamodb for now.
I've been doing scans on the tables for a while now without exploring other querying methods.  The charges spiked in Nov-Dec last year; I took a backup of the tables and deleted them in order to work on some other projects. Started working on it again since 2 weeks and haven't incurred any charges.

Comment: Do you want to do this just for the shake of cost or there is other reason as well? There are many others open source nosql db which can be used via hosting on either EC2 or ECS which will save your cost. S3 cost will be depends on the frequency of object access. I woukd suggest you to use aws price calculator  on the basis of your requirment and take the right decision.

Comment: The move is just for the sake of cost.  I want to stay with either DynamoDB or S3 solely because of ease of triggering lambda.

Comment: If you want recommendations that take cost into account, you need to share details about how you access the data. How frequently do you read each item? How frequently do you write to each item? Is there any limit on how long you retain the data? Do you need any query ability? What sort of latency requirements do you have? What sort of consistency requirements do you have?

Comment: I need to access the data quite frequently.  Every time the Lambda is invoked it scans a couple of tables.  I do a lot of scan, update and write actions.  I don't have strict latency requirements though.

Comment: why do you need to do scan? can you please share your db schema?

Comment: The frequent scans are what is making it expensive. You need to alter your schema to match your access patterns and avoid scans. So like best wishes wrote, we need to see your schema, but in addition we need to see what your access patterns are so we can match them up.

Answer (score 1):

It is tempting to use s3 as data store, but you will hit limitations like below

1. S3 response times are not consistent,as less as dynamodb. (Please do a performance test putting same data in s3 and dynamodb and do a fetch).
2. There will not be any get all messages sort by last modified date support.
3. There will not be a partial retrieval of json. unless you denormalize everything. Which will be a huge performance hit considering s3 response times are more than dynamodb.
4. It is almost impossible to store a relational model into flat key value without any relationship among stored files apart from probably a file.

Considering the above points, I would not have used s3 as a data store for a relational use case.